# Google AppEngine - Integrate Google Applications Toolbar

Tags: google-app-engine, google-toolbar

I'm wondering if in my GAE project i can add to the head of the page the Application Toolbar. The launcher that you can configure with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-launcher-customizer-f/ponjkmladgjfjgllmhnkhgbgocdigcjm).

Does Google provide the integration of the entire toolbar? (Search Engine, G+ notifications, applications launcher, Profile settings, ...) for Web (or only GAE based) applications?

So i can go to GMail, Calendar, ... even if i'm using my GAE application

Comment: AFAIK the Google bar is reserved for 1st party applications, i.e. those developed by Google and running on *.google.com. There's no library/JS snippet that you can embed to show that bar on a 3rd party site. You can of course re-implement part of the toolbar yourself (probably without the notifications, G+ share dialog or profile picture)

Comment: Btw, that extension isn't developed by Google and requires a lot of permissions. Be careful.

Comment: @PhilippReichart Yes, i know. Thank you. I published it only as example